# How to accept both filenames and file-like objects in Python functions?

Tags: python, file-io

In my code, I have a `load_dataset` function that reads a text file and does some processing. Recently I thought about adding support to file-like objects, and I wondered over the best approach to this. Currently I have two implementations in mind:

First, type checking:

```
if isinstance(inputelement, basestring):
   # open file, processing etc
# or
# elif hasattr(inputelement, "read"):
elif isinstance(inputelement, file):
   # Do something else
```

Alternatively, two different arguments:

```
def load_dataset(filename=None, stream=None):
    if filename is not None and stream is None:
        # open file etc
    elif stream is not None and filename is None:
        # do something else
```

Both solutions however don't convince me too much, especially the second as I see way too many pitfalls.

What is the cleanest (and most Pythonic) way to accept a file-like object or string to a function that does text reading?

Comment: If you're going to use the `isinstance` method, don't check to see if it's a `file` -- `open` it if it's a `basestring`, and then assume that you've got a `file` object one way or the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't accept both files and strings.  If you're going to accept file-like objects, then it means you won't check the type, just call the required methods on the actual parameter (`read`, `write`, etc.). If you're going to accept strings, then you're going to end up `open`-ing files, which means you won't be able to mock the parameters. So I'd say accept files, let the caller pass you a file-like object, and don't check the type.

Comment: @rm: Aren't you just moving the problem to where the file is actually opened?

Comment: I think it's a good advice, add obj=None argument to your code. def f(str_arg=None, file_obj=None). You can use it as f("str") or f(file_obj=file). Gzip works so

Comment: @Nicola: if `with open(fname, "r") as f:` is too complicated or ugly for you, you can even define a wrapper to call it like `with read(fname) as f:`. This is probably as simple as it can get without using the approach **varela** described.

Comment: @Niklas: I meant to imply that rm didn't convince me that you shouldn't accept both files and strings as arguments. If you don't take strings some other piece of code will have to open the file and the point of not being able to mock the parameters will apply to that piece of code.

Comment: That other piece of code would however not need to worry about file-like objects, as it would only accept strings. This is IMHO cleaner than trying to figure out the type of the argument passed in every function that takes file-like arguments. If we chose that approach, we also don't have to worry about strings not necessarily meaning file names. They could also be URLs, for example. We can have another wrapper `read_url` for that case, which would make the calling code very self-explanatory.

Comment: @Nicola - you can use a `file` or `StringIO` or anything you want to mock it with.  Your test code could use one type of object, your regular code another. The function shouldn't be tightly coupled to that choice. Yes, at some point some line will have to decide what type of object to pass in, I'm saying that line shouldn't be in the function instead it should be in the different callers.

Comment: I also don't understand the objection to opening files. There's no reason you can't test code with both file-like and filename parameters.

Answer (score 11):

One way of having either a file name or a file-like object as argument is the implementation of a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) that can handle both. An implementation can be found [here](http://reliablybroken.com/b/2012/06/a-context-manager-for-files-or-file-like-objects/), I quote for the sake of a self contained answer:

```
class open_filename(object):
"""Context manager that opens a filename and closes it on exit, but does
nothing for file-like objects.
"""
def __init__(self, filename, *args, **kwargs):
    self.closing = kwargs.pop('closing', False)
    if isinstance(filename, basestring):
        self.fh = open(filename, *args, **kwargs)
        self.closing = True
    else:
        self.fh = filename

def __enter__(self):
    return self.fh

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    if self.closing:
        self.fh.close()

    return False
```

Possible usage then:

```
def load_dataset(file_):
    with open_filename(file_, "r") as f:
        # process here, read only if the file_ is a string
```

Comment: I really wish this were a more active question — this seems like a solid way to approach this, but the lack of comments and upvotes makes me worry that there are edge cases I'm not seeing, and I've not dealt with custom context managers before so I don't trust my lack of seeing to be evidence of code solidity.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using a context manager wrapper. When it's a filename (str), close the file on exit.

```py
@contextmanager
def fopen(filein, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(filein, str):  # filename
        with open(filein, *args, **kwargs) as f:
            yield f
    else:  # file-like object
        yield filein
```

Then you can use it like:

```py
with fopen(filename_or_fileobj) as f:
    # do sth. with f
```

Comment: This does not support path-like objects

Answer (score 2):

Python follows duck typing, you may check that this is file object by function that you need from object. For example `hasattr(obj, 'read')` against `isinstance(inputelement, file)`.
For converting string to file objects you may also use such construction:

```
if not hasattr(obj, 'read'):
    obj = StringIO(str(obj))
```

After this code you will safely be able to use `obj` as a file.

Comment: This isn't what he means -- he wants to use the string as a filename, not as the data for a file-like object.

Comment: `hasattr` has several problems. Rather try to access the `read` attribute and if an `AttributeError` occurs, assume that the parameter is a filename. But as **rm** suggested, it is cleaner to only accept file-like objects. You can also accept to keyword arguments, `filename=None` and `fileobj=None`, and use the first one that is not `None`. **EDIT:** credit goes to **varela**, as he had this though first :P